# Where does VisualStudio store the region states?

Tags: visual-studio

Has anyone ever wondered where VisualStudio stores the states of regions in the source code (expanded or collapsed?). As far as I can see they are not stored in the solution, the project or the source file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are stored in the .suo file.

Answer (score 6):

All of those types of settings (region collapse state, solution explorer open/close state, currently open files, etc...) are stored in the `.suo` file that resides next to your solution file.

If you delete the `.suo` file, you will lose this state, but not lose anything pertinent to the actual solution/code. Many people exclude this file from source control as it contains user-specific data.